# Using custom package view templates for email verification notification

Tags: laravel

I'm sending email verification by extending VerifyEmail in my custom package:

```
<?php

namespace MyPackages\Foo\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class VerifyEmail extends \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail
{
    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        $hash = Crypt::encrypt($notifiable->getKey());

        return config('foo.email_verify_url') . $hash;
    }
}
```

It's correctly using the url from `config/foo.php` in `Foo` package.

But how to tell it to use the templates which are in the two following folders:

```
packages/my-packages/foo/src/resources/views/vendor/mail
packages/my-packages/foo/src/resources/views/vendor/notifications
```

instead of the templates in:

```
resources/views/vendor/mail
resources/views/vendor/notifications
```

Knowing that I also have...

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/views', 'foo');
```

...set in my package provider.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Handling views in custom Laravel packages is documented here: [Package development - views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#views)

**Option 1: Views in your Laravel installation**

In `config/view.php` you can add additional paths where your views are located - [see the config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/view.php#L16).

```php
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        // ...
    ],
```

**Option 2: Custom package**

If you ship your views inside a custom package, the you would need to publish your views.

1. In your service provider specify the package views folder

```php
    protected function loadViews()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'foo');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../resources/views' => resource_path('views/vendor/foo'),
        ]);
    }
```

2. Then run `artisan vendor:publish` ([Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#publishing-views)) to make them available to your main application.